# KSQL Hopping Window : any way to get only one record in response?

Tags: ksqldb

We are using KSQL to perform some aggregations / filtering on a real time data.
One of the use case we have is, we need to perform some operation on last N days of a particular activity, this would be continuous operation.
So this needs to be hopping window.

When I tried the query, with hopping duration as M days, KSQL query returned M records instead of 1 (which was hoping for).

Query :

```
select PROTO, 
       TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(WindowStart(), 'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss''Z''', 'UTC') as "timestamp", 
       TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(WindowEnd(), 'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss''Z''', 'UTC'), 
       COUNT(PROTO) AS Count 
  FROM DATASTREAM  
         WINDOW HOPPING (SIZE 5 DAYS, ADVANCE BY 1 DAY) 
 WHERE MSG like '%SOMESTRING%' 
   AND SPLIT(PROTO, '/')[0] = 'tcp' 
 GROUP BY PROTO; 

tcp/22 | 2020-01-27T00:00:00Z | 2020-02-01T00:00:00Z | 1
tcp/22 | 2020-01-28T00:00:00Z | 2020-02-02T00:00:00Z | 1
tcp/22 | 2020-01-29T00:00:00Z | 2020-02-03T00:00:00Z | 1
tcp/22 | 2020-01-30T00:00:00Z | 2020-02-04T00:00:00Z | 1
tcp/22 | 2020-01-31T00:00:00Z | 2020-02-05T00:00:00Z | 1
```

Is there any way to get only first record only, or the records for which end time <= current time or any other workaround to get 1 result per window ?

---

Please consider below data records.

```
{ "time": "2020-01-25 23:36:37 UTC", "msg": "Error"} 
{ "time": "2020-01-25 23:36:38 UTC", "msg": "Error"} 
{ "time": "2020-01-25 23:36:40 UTC", "msg": "Error"} 
{ "time": "2020-01-26 23:36:37 UTC", "msg": "Error"} 
{ "time": "2020-01-26 23:36:38 UTC", "msg": "Error"} 
{ "time": "2020-01-26 23:36:39 UTC", "msg": "Error"} 
{ "time": "2020-01-26 23:36:40 UTC", "msg": "Error"} 
{ "time": "2020-01-27 23:36:37 UTC", "msg": "Error"} 
{ "time": "2020-01-27 23:36:38 UTC", "msg": "Error"} 
{ "time": "2020-01-27 23:36:39 UTC", "msg": "Error"} 
{ "time": "2020-01-28 23:36:37 UTC", "msg": "Error"} 
{ "time": "2020-01-28 23:36:38 UTC", "msg": "Error"} 
{ "time": "2020-01-29 23:36:37 UTC", "msg": "Error"} 
{ "time": "2020-01-29 23:36:38 UTC", "msg": "Error"} 
{ "time": "2020-01-29 23:36:39 UTC", "msg": "Error"} 
{ "time": "2020-01-29 23:36:40 UTC", "msg": "Error"}
```

I am looking for count of records which have, *msg* as *Error* past 2 days.

If I fire the KSQL query on 25th at 23:36:37, I would be expecting result as :

```
2020-01-25T23:36:37Z | 1
2020-01-25T23:36:38Z | 2
2020-01-25T23:36:40Z | 3

2020-01-26T23:36:37Z | 4
2020-01-26T23:36:38Z | 5
2020-01-26T23:36:39Z | 6
2020-01-26T23:36:40Z | 7

2020-01-27T23:36:37Z | 5
2020-01-27T23:36:38Z | 6
2020-01-27T23:36:39Z | 7

2020-01-28T23:36:37Z | 4
2020-01-28T23:36:38Z | 5

2020-01-29T23:36:37Z | 3
2020-01-29T23:36:38Z | 4
2020-01-29T23:36:39Z | 5
2020-01-29T23:36:40Z | 6
```

Comment: This is the issue which will enable the required functionality; https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/4397

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `TUMBLING` window instead if you want one window for the five day period. You're instead getting five windows because you've used `HOPPING` with an advance of `1 DAY` - see the `WINDOWSTART()` changes per day.

References:

- [Hopping windows twitter thread](https://threader.app/thread/1214216607049764868)
- [Tumbling windows twitter thread](https://threadreaderapp.com/thread/1202991669219512321.html)
- https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/concepts/time-and-windows-in-ksqldb-queries/
- https://rmoff.net/2020/01/09/exploring-ksqldb-window-start-time/

Comment: Ok, understood why it is behaving that way. But I can't use Tumbling window either, the windows would be non overlapping in that case, right ?
The use case was to get Last N days of data continuously,
Agg. data (one data point) for 1st Jan to 1st Feb, 2nd Jan to 2nd Feb, and so on.
If I don't get any other solution, I was thinking, may be just run the tumbling query once, kill it, do it again next day ?

Comment: When data for the tumbling window is received, the aggregate is updated and re-emitted. Maybe I don't understand your question fully. Could you update it with an example set of input records and your desired output?

Comment: Agree, but in tumbling window the counter will be initialised after the window is over.
It won't keep track of partial window. 
Sorry for being unclear, I have updated the question with the example. Please let me know if I need to add any information.